# Adding a configurable item to cart via ajax

Tags: cart, configurable-product, ajax, magento2.2.7, ajaxaddtocart

I've inherited a project which lists configurable products in the catalog view, as well as listing the simple products attached to that configurable product. For example;

```
Configurable Product: Sandpaper
Items: 40grit sand paper, 50grit sand paper, 60grit sandpaper.
```

We've had to upgrade from 2.2.2 to 2.2.7, which has caused the ajax add to cart we were using to stop working.

I've attempted to debug as best I can, but I'm just about ready to throw the computer out the window.

According to the original solution, making a POST request to

```
http://{website}/{category}/{configurable-product-page}.html?options=cart
```

With the following payload

```
form_key: "nEcvSLTQFbHNKTNJ"
product: "2014"
qty: "2"
super_attribute[173]: 81
super_attribute[174]: 83
super_attribute[223]: 326
uenc: "aHR0cDovL2RyYWtlLmxvY2FsL2FicmFzaXZlcy8xMTVtbS1nYXJyeXNvbi1jZXJhbWlxLWZsYXAtZGlzY3MuaHRtbD9vcHRpb25zPWNhcnQ,"
```

Should add to product to the cart. Instead, it no longer does this and throws me a front end error of

"You need to choose options for your item."

The response from the server is to just return

```
{backUrl: "http://{website}/{category}/{configurable-product-page}.html?options=cart"}
```

What do?